# How do I make the console appear?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

How do I make the console appear in Chivalry? Apparently this should be the tilde key (<kbd>~</kbd>) but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the key to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key on the number row. On American keyboards, this is <kbd>~</kbd> which is why most tutorials mention the shortcut as <kbd>~</kbd>, but on my keyboard layout for example, it is <kbd>`</kbd>. This applies to many games.

[Link on this being the case on Chivalry and how to change it](http://steamcommunity.com/app/219640/discussions/0/864950106297894904/)

Comment: Yeah, that's the key I'm familiar with for most other games but isn't working for me on Chivalry. I checked UDKInput.ini which references scroll lock which worked for a friend but my keyboard doesn't have this key.

Comment: Changing the key to 'Insert' worked though!

Comment: In that case you should change the configuration to a key that is available on your keyboard. The available keys and the corresponding config values are available on this page: http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/KeyBinds.html (EDIT: was writing this before I saw your reply)

Comment: On an American keyboard, the key is ` (backtick), but ~ (its shifted version) is much less ambiguous as people can mistake the former for '.

Comment: On some keyboards it's ç aswell.

Answer (score 0):

By default for me and others I know (in the UK on a UK keyboard), in Unreal games such as Chivalry, Red Orchestra and Killing Floor, the key to open console is actually the <kbd>'</kbd> (apostrophe) button.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this myself and accidentally discovered that on my German keyboard, the <kbd>Ö</kbd> key will bring up the console!

Answer (score 0):

By default, on a US keyboard, you would press the <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd> key. I'm not sure how to disable this.